# Angular 5 Update Variable From Shared Data

Tags: angular, observable

In ComponentA  I have a variable that gets its value from a variable in a shared data class. ComponentA looks like this:

```
import { SharedData } from '../../shared/shared.data';
...
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
  TheSelectedClient = this.SharedData.SelectedClient;

  constructor(
    private SharedData: SharedData,
  ) { }
```

And the shared data class looks like this:

```
export class SharedData {
    SelectedClient = 'Client One';
```

But when I update the `SharedData.SelectedClient = 'Client Two'` from a different component, then `TheSelectedClient` in ComponentA doesn't update by itself. How do I make `TheSelectedClient` automatically update when `SharedData.SelectedClient` updates?

I feel like the answer is in Observables but I don't exactly understand how to use it. I tried reading up on it but it is hard to understand :(

Comment: For that you can use `@Input` and `@Output` decorators with `EventEmitter` in order to capture the change in child, or you can use `@ViewChild`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274721/angular2-difference-between-decoraters) answer for distinction between decorators.

Comment: I know about these but are these not bad practice?

Comment: You can use `Subject` and `Observable` like explain in the Angular official guide : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 1):

You need to create observable and subscribe to its value when changes occured. Try this -

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export class SharedData {
    private SelectedClient = new BehaviorSubject(any);
    SelectedClientObs = this.SelectedClient.asObservable();

    SelectedClientCall(updatedValue) {
      this.SelectedClient.next(updatedValue);
    }
}

import { SharedData } from '../../shared/shared.data';

export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
  TheSelectedClient : null;

  constructor(
    private SharedData: SharedData,
  ) { 
    this.SharedData.SelectedClientObs.subscribe(res => {
      // Here you get the update value
      this.TheSelectedClient = res;
    }); 
  }
```

For more information you can refer official documentation for the same here

- https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Here the component is inserted as a new object in every component.You can use service and provide it at root level(appModule) to treat as a singleton.

Thanks