# Angular 5: generate DIV instead of new tag from component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to know if there's a way to tell Angular to generate a DIV instead of a new tag when inserting a component in a router-outlet. Right now, I have this component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fwc-vpn-main',
  templateUrl: './fwc-vpn-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fwc-vpn-main.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class FwcVpnMainComponent implements OnInit {

  numbers = new Array(35);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Which renders to this in the final HTML:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-fwc-vpn-main class="ng-star-inserted"> ... </app-fwc-vpn-main>
```

What I would need is to generate a div with some added classes, so the final result would be something like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div app-fwc-vpn-main class="grid-y medium-grid-frame"> ... </div>
```

NOTE: I need to add the `grid-y` and `medium-grid-frame` classes so the app has the correct layout. This is the main reason I want to change the inserted tag for this div.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: despite what has been said, a directive is the correct way to go

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Please create example to show us that it's working

Comment: @yurzui see https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#write-the-directive-code

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Show us example with router. I know how to create directive

Comment: @yurzui if you know how to create a directive, why are you arguing against them?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I would like to see how you will adopt directive to be used in angular router with empty template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166244/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In angular [selector may be declared](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) as one of the following:

- `element-name`: select by element name.
- `.class`: select by class name.
- `[attribute]`: select by attribute name.
- `[attribute=value]`: select by attribute name and value.
- `:not(sub_selector)`: select only if the element does not match the `sub_selector`.
- `selector1, selector2`: select if either `selector1` or `selector2` matches.

So when angular compiles Component/Directive metadata it parses selector by using [CssSelector](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/selector.ts#L28) and keep all parsed data like:

```
[
  {
    "element": null,
    "classNames": [
      "grid-y",
      "medium-grid-frame"
    ],
    "attrs": [
      "app-fwc-vpn-main",
      ""
    ],
    "notSelectors": []
  }
]
```

Angular router creates component dynamically so each of our routed components will have Host view. For Host view angular compiler [prepares](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/235a235fab45b2c82f8758fc9c0779f62a5b6c04/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L172-L181) template based on metadata received from CssSelector:

```
/** Gets a template string for an element that matches the selector. */
getMatchingElementTemplate(): string {
    const tagName = this.element || 'div';
    const classAttr = this.classNames.length > 0 ? ` class="${this.classNames.join(' ')}"` : '';

    let attrs = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.attrs.length; i += 2) {
      const attrName = this.attrs[i];
      const attrValue = this.attrs[i + 1] !== '' ? `="${this.attrs[i + 1]}"` : '';
      attrs += ` ${attrName}${attrValue}`;
   }

   return getHtmlTagDefinition(tagName).isVoid ? `<${tagName}${classAttr}${attrs}/>` :
                                                  `<${tagName}${classAttr}${attrs}></${tagName}>`;
 }
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/compiler/src/selector.ts#L91-L105

After that host template will be like:

```
<div class="grid-y medium-grid-frame" app-fwc-vpn-main></div>
```

So the following should work for you:

```
selector: '[app-fwc-vpn-main].grid-y.medium-grid-frame',
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/YPLo7K42wBiI5rdo24El)**

Comment: That worked! Please, can you send a link to any documentation that explains this syntax? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fel , please checkout the link I have posted in answer that would be enough for the component's each property

Comment: @yurzui thanks for the explanation! Do you know if there is way to select based on element and attribute? E.g. `nz-content[example]`

Answer (score 2):

Then change the `selector` from :

```
selector: 'app-fwc-vpn-main',
```

To

```
selector: '[app-fwc-vpn-main]',
```

And then you can use it like `<div app-fwc-vpn-main></div>`

> @Component selector - css selector that identifies this component in a
>   template
>
> So you can use any css selector like
>
> ```
> .app-fwc-vpn-main // <div class='app-fwc-vpn-main'></div>
> #app-fwc-vpn-main // <div id='app-fwc-vpn-main'></div>
> ```

For more details read : **[Component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component)**

Comment: A `@Directive` would need to be used in order for `app-fwc-vpn-main` to be a property as such on the div

Comment: @mast3rd3mon About which property are you talking about?

Comment: `app-fwc-vpn-main`, for that to belong on a div like so `<div app-fwc-vpn-main>...</div>` it would need to be a directive

Comment: @mast3rd3mon , If it looks/use like attribute it doesn't means it should be directve.

Comment: properties should be inputs/outputs, attributes (thats the work i meant) should be directives

Answer (score -1):

Create a directive instead of a component

```
<div app-fwc-vpn-main class="grid-y medium-grid-frame"> ... </div>
```

In this case app-fwc-vpn-main is the directive. Instead of creating a component you can create a directive and render your desired template.

Comment: And why is that ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi because the `app-fwc-vpn-main` needs to be a directive to be used how @Fel wants

Comment: Nope , This is not how things goes , @mast3rd3mon , Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680244/directive-v-s-component-in-angular

Comment: Just one question... How are you going to work with component template?

Comment: @yurzui probably people who understand what a '@Directive` is and why it is needed in this case

Comment: @yurzui , me too