# Can generated component tags change?

Tags: angular

I receive HTML/CSS documents to be written in Angular/cli.

CSS file use single selectors like "section > section > div"
But generated HTML contains non standard "components tags" breaking those selectors..

Instead of changing all my CSS, Is it posible that each component generates standard tags like section or div instead of app-component tag?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, you will have to rewrite your css.

Answer (score 0):

From [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110383/angular-5-generate-div-instead-of-new-tag-from-component):

> In angular [selector may be declared](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) as one of the following:
>
> - `element-name`: select by element name.
> - `.class`: select by class name.
> - `[attribute]`: select by attribute name.
> - `[attribute=value]`: select by attribute name and value.
> - `:not(sub_selector)`: select only if the element does not match the `sub_selector`.
> - `selector1, selector2`: select if either `selector1` or `selector2` matches.

---

So you could create a component by a div class or attribute. I strongly recommend amending the CSS instead.